How do I check for undercuts in Blender
I'm attempting to mass produce a model I made in Blender using injection molding process. The manufacture says I have undercuts in my model. An undercut is a geometry or angle in your model that will snag the mold, after the piece material has been injected, preventing the 2 part mold from being pulled apart.
Does anyone how to check for undercuts in Blender? Or maybe there is a seperate program that I could import my model to check?
Other programs like Solidworks have "check for undercut" type programs. I understand Blender is not meant for manufacturing, so it may not have this feature, but the design I made is one that has many organic type geometries that I produced using the sculpting feature, which I didn't think could be created using traditional CAD programs. (Maybe i'm wrong here, but this was my novice understanding).
Thank you!

There is a built-in addon called 3DPrint ToolBox. I think it should have alot of what you need for validating 3D Print meshes.

Yes, but 3D printing and injection molding have different requirements. I need to specifically check for undercuts.

Would checking for undercuts and checking for overhangs not essentially be the same thing? That addon has an operator to check for that.

I searched around online, and didn't find anything about undercuts vs. overhangs. My novice intuition says no, they are slightly different. But I would love to be wrong here.

I'm pretty sure the difference between the two is negligible in this context. They both just indicate a part of the 3d model that sticks out too far from the core volume of the mesh. In 3D printing it means that part lacks support, in molding it just means it might trap bubbles or complicate pulling it from the mold. Can you possibly share a blend file or at least post a few images of what the model looks like and the kind of places in the mesh you need to be checking for?

Instructions for sharing your Blender project file.

@Jakemoyo I can't add the file because I'd rather not have it on the internet if I want to manufacture, but I added I picture. The product is a fake poop. This is a side profile picture, where the manufacture has pointed out a few regions that have undercuts.
